# Retrieve Rules from Agenda in Drools 8

Tags: java, drools

I am using Drools 8 Rule Engine. I want to retrieve the Rules in the Agenda for viewing purposes. Unable to find a straightforward way of extracting the rules in the Agenda. Any tips?

I have tried going through the Agenda, AgendaGroup Activations and their concrete implementations. They don't yield the rules I am expecting in the agenda.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API available to introspect this programmatically, but you can use internal model API (by casting Rule model objects to `org.drools.core.definitions.rule.impl.RuleImpl`).

For example, given a rule such as:

```
rule "will execute per each Measurement having ID color"
agenda-group "agroup1"
when
    Measurement( id == "color", $colorVal : val )
then
    controlSet.add($colorVal);
end
```

the following code snippet:

```java
LOG.info("There should be rules: ");
for ( KiePackage kp : kieBase.getKiePackages() ) {
    for (Rule rule : kp.getRules()) {
        LOG.info("package '{}' rule named '{}' belongs in agenda group: {}",
                kp.getName(),
                rule.getName(),
                ((RuleImpl) rule).getAgendaGroup());
    }
}
```

would print out:

> 2023-04-05 08:50:07,215 [main] INFO  package 'org.drools.demo' rule
> named 'will execute per each Measurement having ID color' belongs in
> agenda group: agroup1

tested with: https://github.com/tarilabs/demo20230405-so75934570/blob/1d70e459e05aaf319e8171ef11f649d1027c0a56/src/test/java/org/drools/demo/RuleTest.java#L37

Comment: Thank you for your response @tarilabs. The test returns the rules but not the one in the agenda. However, this helps me dig deeper.

Comment: it return packages -> rule and for each rule in each package, the agenda of the rule. With that, you can construct the inverse relationship of a given agenda, which rules are part of said agenda.

Comment: I am unable to see how I can get from packages -> package -> rules -> rule -> agenda!

Comment: You original question was: `Retrieve Rules from Agenda`. So given a specific agenda, you can filter using this snippet provided in answer for the rules in that agenda. This snippet of code list for each package the rules which are contained, and for each rule the associated agenda. You just need to filter for your given agenda.